# Elementos com Tipo de dados de Data e Hora

Tags: java, data, view

Pessoal Gostaria de tirar uma duvida, devemos tratar de forma diferente campos que tem como tipo de dados hora e data digo em relação ao view, por que estou com um problema preciso plotar algumas data e horas em um tabela no meu view porem os campos que não são data e nem hora aparecem numa boa já os campos que tem como tipo hora e data aparecem como Object

```
public static List<FolhaBean> bindingProperties(List<Folha> folhas) {

        List<FolhaBean> folhasBean = new ArrayList<>();

        folhas.forEach(folha -> {

            FolhaBean folhaBean = new FolhaBean(folha.getIdFolha(), folha.getData(), folha.getEntrada(), 
                    folha.getSaidaAlmoco(), folha.getVoltaAlmoco(),folha.getSaida(), folha.getBancoHoraNegativo()
                    , folha.getBancoHoraPositivo(), folha.getVersion(), folha.getNomeUsuario());

            folhasBean.add(folhaBean);
        });

        return folhasBean;
    }
```

esse eh o bean que estou usando para trazer as informações

```
@RequestMapping(value = REDIRECT_PAGE_CARREGAR, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView showCarregar(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

        usuarioBean= folhaService.findFetchAll();


        model.addAttribute("usuarioBean", usuarioBean);


        return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_CARREGAR);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/carregarDados", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<FolhaBean>> carregar() {

        List<Folha> folhas = folhaService.findFetchAll();

        List<FolhaBean> folhasBean = FolhaBean.bindingProperties(folhas);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<FolhaBean>>(folhasBean, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

e esse o controller.

[image: Fica assim]

o codigo que gera a tabela é esse

id="" data-url="${carregarFolha}" data-content-type="application/json" data-page-size="5" data-locale="pt-BR" data-minimum-count-columns="2" data-show-toggle="true" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" data-id-field="id" data-show-refresh="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-query-params="paginar" data-select-item-name="" data-pagination="true" data-pagination-pre-text="Anterior" data-pagination-next-text="Próximo" data-checkbox-header="false" data-search="true" data-response-handler="responseHandler">    id Data Entrada Saida Almoço Volta Almoço Saida Banco Positivo Banco Negativo Usuario Licença

Comment: Pode adicionar o trecho de código problemático?

Comment: Objetos do tipo *Date/Time* costumam requerir a chamada de um método `format` para exibição. Não seria o caso?

Comment: então essa é a minha duvida não sei se precisa de um tratamento diferente

Comment: Como é exibido na sua view? Algo assim: `Tue Apr 11 13:41:42 GMT 2017`?

Comment: entao no momento é apresentado como Object apenas

Comment: não é apresentado nenhuma data nem hora

Comment: Não entendi. Poste uma imagem do problema, de preferencia.

Comment: veja que o id aparece normal mais os campos que sao data e hora fica como object

Comment: Isso parece ser um erro no JavaScript, não no Java. Qual é o código que gera esta tabela?

Comment: eu criei uma ideia de tabela dinamica e não tabela statica

Comment: Rapaz consegui resolver era apenas um problema de conversão agradeço demais a atençao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já foi resolvido o problema esta na forma que eu estava acessando o objeto.

Eu estava acessando o objeto de forma direta, porem depois que dei uma olhada no json vi que precisava acessar o objeto e depois os atributos desse mesmo objeto, ex  usuario.nome.